# Run all JUnit test multiple times with different setting value

Tags: spring-boot, maven, junit

How can I run all the JUnit tests of a spring boot application two times?
First time with a custom parameter (say a.b="one") in application.yml and the second time with a.b="two"

What needs to be configured?
I assume changes will be necessary in JUnit test classes and in pom.xml

I can mark a
`@WebMvcTest`

With
`@TestPropertySource(properties = "a.b=one")`

or with
`@TestPropertySource(properties = "a.b=two")`

and it will use that option during execution. But how to run it twice with these two different options? Is it somehow doable with
`org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest` ?

Comment: Maybe Parameterized Tests are your answer.

Comment: @duffymo Do you have an example with an option from application.yml involved in this? It would also be great if I didn't have to mark all the test classes with some annotation

Comment: No, it wouldn't be in application.yml.  You'd have to specify all the beans you needed and then look them up in code.  The parameters for the test would be the bean name you needed to use.  I don't like your use case much.  I wouldn't do such things.